# OpenSAML dependencies in spring-security-saml

Tags: spring-saml

spring-saml uses OpenSAML:

1. spring-security-saml 1.0.1 references to an older opensaml version. Is it a good idea to upgrade to the most current version (2.6.6)?
2. [OpenSAML V2 will not supported soon](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home). Does this affect spring-security-saml? Will there be a major change of spring-saml in the near future?

Or are these topics only relevant to SAML IDP implementations (see last sentence on [annoucement](http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/announce/2015-May/000112.html))?

maven dependencies:

```
 +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
```